# How to define a rule to match with a pattern multiple times in PEG.js?

Tags: peg

I'm trying to parse a file where the pattern might be seen multiple times:

```
G04 hello world*
G04 foo bar*
```

The corresponding [PEG.js](https://pegjs.org/online) grammar is:

```
Comment
  = "G04" _ content:String* _ EOL
  {
    return content
  }

_ "whitespace"
  = [ \t\n\r]*

String
  = value:[a-zA-Z0-9.(): _-]+
  {
    return value.join('') 
  }

EOL
  = [*] _
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> Line 2, column 1: Expected end of input but "G" found.

How do I make this `Comment` rule to match multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to add a new start rule that matches multiple `Comment`s:

```
Comments
  = Comment+

Comment
  = "G04" _ content:String* _ EOL
  {
    return content
  }

_ "whitespace"
  = [ \t\n\r]*

String
  = value:[a-zA-Z0-9.(): _-]+
  {
    return value.join('') 
  }

EOL
  = [*] _
```

Output:

```
[
   [
      "hello world"
   ],
   [
      "foo bar"
   ]
]
```